# Hide/Unhide Rows

Tags: excel, hide, rows, vba

I'm currently working with three sheets. The first one includes all lists and datas. In the second one which is called Input, you can choose between different variables in lists.
Depending on what you've chosen in the the Input sheet, in the output sheet the content is displayed.

For example I have a list in the "Input" Sheet where you're able to choose the number of the underlying.
When choosing for example 2 everything works well and in the sheet "output" the rows are hidden.
Switching from 2 to for example 13 it would not work anymore and it still shows the content of number 2.

Do you know where my mistake is?

I'm working with the following code:

```
If Target.Address = "$F$8" Then 'Underlying numbers
If Target.Value = "1" Then
Sheets("Output").Rows("66:84").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("183:201").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("226:244").Hidden = True
Else
If Target.Value = "2" Then
Sheets("Output").Rows("67:84").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("184:201").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("227:244").Hidden = True
Else
If Target.Value = "3" Then
Sheets("Output").Rows("68:84").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("185:201").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("228:244").Hidden = True
Else
If Target.Value = "4" Then
Sheets("Output").Rows("69:84").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("186:201").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("229:244").Hidden = True
Else
If Target.Value = "5" Then
Sheets("Output").Rows("70:84").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("187:201").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("230:244").Hidden = True
Else
If Target.Value = "6" Then
Sheets("Output").Rows("71:84").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("188:201").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("231:244").Hidden = True
Else
If Target.Value = "7" Then
Sheets("Output").Rows("72:84").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("189:201").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("232:244").Hidden = True
Else
If Target.Value = "8" Then
Sheets("Output").Rows("73:84").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("190:201").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("233:244").Hidden = True
Else
If Target.Value = "9" Then
Sheets("Output").Rows("74:84").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("191:201").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("234:244").Hidden = True
Else
If Target.Value = "10" Then
Sheets("Output").Rows("75:84").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("192:201").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("235:244").Hidden = True
Else
If Target.Value = "11" Then
Sheets("Output").Rows("76:84").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("193:201").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("236:244").Hidden = True
Else
If Target.Value = "12" Then
Sheets("Output").Rows("77:84").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("194:201").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("237:244").Hidden = True
Else
If Target.Value = "13" Then
Sheets("Output").Rows("78:84").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("195:201").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("238:244").Hidden = True
Else
If Target.Value = "14" Then
Sheets("Output").Rows("79:84").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("196:201").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("239:244").Hidden = True
Else
If Target.Value = "15" Then
Sheets("Output").Rows("80:84").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("197:201").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("240:244").Hidden = True
Else
If Target.Value = "16" Then
Sheets("Output").Rows("81:84").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("198:201").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("241:244").Hidden = True
Else
If Target.Value = "17" Then
Sheets("Output").Rows("82:84").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("199:201").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("242:244").Hidden = True
Else
If Target.Value = "18" Then
Sheets("Output").Rows("83:84").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("200:201").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("243:244").Hidden = True
Else
If Target.Value = "19" Then
Sheets("Output").Rows("84").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("201").Hidden = True
Sheets("Output").Rows("244").Hidden = True
Else
Sheets("Output").Rows("66:84").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("183:201").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("226:244").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("67:84").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("184:201").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("227:244").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("68:84").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("185:201").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("228:244").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("69:84").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("186:201").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("229:244").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("70:84").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("187:201").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("230:244").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("71:84").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("188:201").Hidden = False    
Sheets("Output").Rows("231:244").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("72:84").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("189:201").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("232:244").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("73:84").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("190:201").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("233:244").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("74:84").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("191:201").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("234:244").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("75:84").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("192:201").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("235:244").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("76:84").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("193:201").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("236:244").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("77:84").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("194:201").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("237:244").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("78:84").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("195:201").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("238:244").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("79:84").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("196:201").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("239:244").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("80:84").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("197:201").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("240:244").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("81:84").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("198:201").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("241:244").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("82:84").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("199:201").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("242:244").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("83:84").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("200:201").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("243:244").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("84").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("201").Hidden = False
Sheets("Output").Rows("244").Hidden = False
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If
```

Comment: Hi. First thing i'd point out is to use 'ElseIf' for different conditions, as opposed to 'Else' and then 'If' (with the additional myriad of End If statements you have to put in). Secondly I think the reason it wont show when moving in-between different conditions is that you haven't unhidden all rows at each step, so the rows from the setting before (ie 2 in your example) would still be hidden when another setting (13 in your example) is triggered.

Comment: In summary, I think you need to re-organise your If statement structure. See this useful link :) https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_then.php

Comment: @excelnewbie no, no , no, don't use so many `If`s in your case, use `Select Case Target.Value` , then `Case "1"` , `Case "2"` , etc...

Comment: Could you please show me an example with the "case" function?

Comment: You can just Google VBA Select Case

Comment: @excelnewbie i'll write it in a seperate post below, but it's not the answer

Comment: @wilson88 elseif doesn't work :/

Comment: @Rdster I already have but I don't know how to implement it into my code

Comment: @ShaiRado could you please give me an example using my code?

Comment: @excelnewbie see below ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short sample of your code using `Select Case`. If this code is inside the `Worksheet_Change` event inside "Output" sheet, then you don't need to use the `With Sheets("Output")` line.

```
With Sheets("Output")

    ' ****** Edit 1 ******
    ' first thing" unhide all hidden rows from previous code run
    .Rows("66:84").Hidden = False
    .Rows("183:201").Hidden = False
    .Rows("226:244").Hidden = False

    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "1"
            .Rows("66:84").Hidden = True
            .Rows("183:201").Hidden = True
            .Rows("226:244").Hidden = True

        Case "2"
            .Rows("67:84").Hidden = True
            .Rows("184:201").Hidden = True
            .Rows("227:244").Hidden = True

        ' rest of your cases 3 thourgh 19.....

        Case Else
            .Rows("66:84").Hidden = False
            .Rows("183:201").Hidden = False
            .Rows("226:244").Hidden = False
            ' the rest of your line here are redundant >> can be removed

    End Select

End With
```

Comment: I have a list with 20 numbers and at each number different rows should be hidden

Comment: Well i tried to use your help to solve my problem but now nothing is hidden. I used this one:

Comment: @excelnewbie did you add all of your cases inside ? i just put a sample of your cases here , not all of them

Answer (score 0):

Or, since it looks like this is actually what you are doing...

```
If Target.Address = "$F$8" Then 'Underlying numbers
  Sheets("Output").Rows("66:84").Hidden = False
  Sheets("Output").Rows("183:201").Hidden = False
  Sheets("Output").Rows("226:244").Hidden = False
  If Target >= 1 And Target <= 19 Then
    Sheets("Output").Rows(65 + Target & ":84").Hidden = True
    Sheets("Output").Rows(182 + Target & ":201").Hidden = True
    Sheets("Output").Rows(225 + Target & ":244").Hidden = True
  End If
End If
```

Based on other comments....this will reset the hidden rows each time, and then hide as needed.

Comment: nice logic in the first section, but you have an error in your `Else` section, remove the `Target & ` part, it should be `Rows("65:84")`.

Comment: What do you mean by "first 3 ones"...Target values of 1, 2 and 3?